# List count numbers larger then n inside .count

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count the number of numbers larger then 0 in a list for example. Can i use larger then, smaller then etc operators inside .count()?

```
test_list = ['0','2','3']
for i in test_list:
    i = int(i)
    larger_zero = test_list.count(i > 0)

print(larger_zero)
```

Its printing `0` and i wonder why? What is the explanation why its printing a zero?

Comment: No you can't. That is evaluating the expression `i  > 0` which will evaluate to `True` or `False` which is never in the list, hence `.count` will return `0`

Comment: You can try list comprehension or check out numpy, numpy.where method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterator with `sum` for that.

```
test_list = ['0', '2', '3']
larger_zero = sum(int(i) > 0 for i in test_list)
print(larger_zero)
```

Which prints:

```
2
```

Note that `int(i) > 0` is either `True` (which `sum` treats as `1`) or `False` (which `sum` treats as `0`). `sum` just adds up all of them, effectively counting how many times `int(i) > 0` is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

`list.count` takes a value, not an expression. `i > 0` evaluates to `False` or `True`, then `test_list.count` checks how many times it occurs in the list, which is 0.

You can do it like this:

```
larger_zero = sum(1 for i in test_list if int(i) > 0)
```

Or you can be a bit hacky and use the fact that `False == 0` and `True == 1`:

```
larger_zero = sum(int(i) > 0 for i in test_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

when u use the operator i>0, it will return true or false. So it will count how many true and false in the list. so better use if statement if u want to return list of the number > 0. For example:

```
test_list = ['0','2','3']
larger_zero = []
for i in range(0, len(test_list)): 
    test_list[i] = int(test_list[i])
    if test_list[i] > 0:
        larger_zero.append(test_list[i])
print(larger_zero)
```

now u will get list of number which is higher than 0. if u want the total count of > 0 u can use length of the new list for example:

```
print(len(larger_zero))
```

if you don't wan to change the data type of the origin list, u can make it like this:

```
    test_list = ['0','2','3']
    larger_zero = []
    for i in range(0, len(test_list)): 
        if int(test_list[i]) > 0:
            larger_zero.append(test_list[i])
    print(larger_zero)
    print(len(larger_zero))
```

Comment: `i > 0` is an expression, not an operator; `>` is an operator. Your code also casts each element of `test_list` to `int`, is that intentional?

Comment: sorry my mistake, it is an expression. yes i intentionally convert the string to int like his coding.. i make the code a bit like his code so he can understand..

Comment: No need to apologize :) About the casting, I mean OP's code casts `i` to int, which doesn't affect the list, but yours casts `test_list[i]` to int, which *does* affect the list.

Comment: yes i edited the list data type but i think he can use or replace it with any other new list if he still doesn't want to change the origin list

Comment: @wjandrea i already edit my answer if he don't wan to change the origin list